# Pattern matching / deconstruction of binaries and bitstrings in Haskell that's similiar to the one of Elixir/Erlang

Tags: string, haskell, erlang, elixir, binary-data

In Elixir/Erlang one can do this kind of pattern matching / deconstruction over binaries and bitstrings:

```
  def func1(my_data) do
      <<
        1,
        44,
        a::little-32,
        b::little-64, 
        c, 
        d::64-little, 
        e::32-little-float, 
        rest::binary
      >> = my_data

      # using a, b, c, d, e, rest 

   end
```

I've not found a way to do that in Haskell. Is there any out of the box capacity of Haskell? Or will utilizing some third-party library be required?

Comment: You can write a parser using one of the parser libraries, such as parsec or attoparsec. Parsing bits out of a `ByteString` takes a little work, but I've done it.

Comment: @BobDalgleish that doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing out of the box, but something similar can be implemented as a library with pattern synonyms, so it would look like this:

```hs
-- For some definition of (:.)
case myData of
  (1 :: Word8) :.
    (44 :: Word8) :.
    (a :: Little32) :.
    (b :: Little64) :.
    (c :: Word8) :.
    (d :: Little64) :.
    (e :: LittleFloat32) :.
    rest ->
    {- using a, b, c, d, e, rest -}
```

Full gist https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/8ee6b9debd613b988023d5a0a8dfd9cc

In Haskell we usually prefer parser combinator libraries like the [*binary* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary).

Comment: what's the type of `myData` in your answer?

Comment: where did you get `LittleFloat32`, `Little64`?

Comment: what's `For some definition of (:.)` ?

Comment: `myData` and `rest` would be `ByteString`. Everything else would need to be defined.

Comment: That's what my initial question is about - how define them?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin а ты бы такое не смог написать - бе-бе-бе

Comment: thx. And if I wanted to cast all of `myData` to a single type, for instance, `LittleFloat32` how would I do that?

Comment: `case myData of { LittleFloat32 n :. rest | BS.null rest -> Just n ; _ -> Nothing }`